# How to query multiple Left Join table when there exist null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 20 tables (list of subjects) that has the same table structure as below.

**columns**

```
|id|student_id|result_session|result_term|result_arm|result_class|result_level|1st_test|2nd_test|exam|result_total|result_grade|result_remark|
```

I then have another table `result_summary` as below:

```
|id|student_id|result_score|result_average|result_term|result_session|result_level|result_class|result_arm
```

**Minimal Query**

When I write my query like so:

```
SELECT        t2.`1st_test` AS agric1, t2.`2nd_test` AS agric2, t2.exam AS agricExam3, t2.result_total AS agricTotal, 
                     t2.result_grade AS agricGrade, t3.`1st_test` AS basicsci1, t3.`2nd_test` AS basicsci2, t3.exam AS basicsciExam, 
                     t3.result_total AS basicsciTotal, t3.result_grade AS basicsciGrade t2.result_remark AS agricRemark, t3.result_remark AS basicSciRemark
FROM            ((result_summary AS t1 LEFT  JOIN
                     agricultural_science AS t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id) LEFT  JOIN
                     basic_science AS t3 ON t1.student_id = t3.student_id)
WHERE         (t1.student_id = '@studentID' AND t1.result_term = '@term' AND t1.result_session = '@session' AND t1.result_level = '@level' AND  t1.result_class = '@resultClass') AND
          (t2.student_id = '@studentID' AND t2.result_term = '@term' AND t2.result_session = '@session' AND t2.result_level = '@level' AND  t2.result_class = '@resultClass') AND
          (t3.student_id = '@studentID' AND t3.result_term = '@term' AND t3.result_session = '@session' AND t3.result_level = '@level' AND  t3.result_class = '@resultClass')
```

It does not return any row. Mind you, there are data matching the query data in table `t1 and t2` but not in `t3`.

How can I write the query to get the desire result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: There data to fetch from table `t1 and t2` which does not occur in table `t3`. Running the query returns zero row but suppose to return one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining `t2` and `t3` table's conditions in where clause turns your left joins into `INNER JOIN`.

The `t2` and `t3` table's conditions will need to be defined in `ON` instead of `WHERE`:

```
select t2.`1st_test` as agric1,
    t2.`2nd_test` as agric2,
    t2.exam as agricExam3,
    t2.result_total as agricTotal,
    t2.result_grade as agricGrade,
    t3.`1st_test` as basicsci1,
    t3.`2nd_test` as basicsci2,
    t3.exam as basicsciExam,
    t3.result_total as basicsciTotal,
    t3.result_grade as basicsciGrade t2.result_remark as agricRemark,
    t3.result_remark as basicSciRemark
from (
    (
        result_summary as t1 left join agricultural_science as t2 on t1.student_id = t2.student_id
        ) left join basic_science as t3 on t1.student_id = t3.student_id
        and (
            t3.student_id = '@studentID'
            and t3.result_term = '@term'
            and t3.result_session = '@session'
            and t3.result_level = '@level'
            and t3.result_class = '@resultClass'
            )
        and (
            t2.student_id = '@studentID'
            and t2.result_term = '@term'
            and t2.result_session = '@session'
            and t2.result_level = '@level'
            and t2.result_class = '@resultClass'
            )
    )
where (
        t1.student_id = '@studentID'
        and t1.result_term = '@term'
        and t1.result_session = '@session'
        and t1.result_level = '@level'
        and t1.result_class = '@resultClass'
        );
```